# joomla bootstrap jquery trouble

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I have a site using joomla with bootstrap. When I try to load jquery with `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`
in the file index.php from the template and use jquery within the article, it gives an error.

in the joomla article:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Evenementen</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="inleidingevenement">
<H2> INSCHRIJVEN VOOR DE EVENEMENTEN </H2>
<p> Hieronder kun je je aanmelden voor de evenementen. Wanneer je status op "Aanwezig" staat, ben je aangemeld voor het desbetreffende evenement. </p>
</div>
<button id="button" class="btn"> </button>

<script src="templates/templatename/js/status.js"> </script>
```

and status.js:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#button" ).click(
    function() {
        $("#button").addClass("btn-primary");
    }
    );
});
```

it gives the error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

the line it refers to is the first line with code `$(document.....`

When I try this in a different file, without joomla e.d. it works fine.
Why is jquery not loaded as expected?

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <base href="https://localhost/index.php/leden/evenementen" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Super User" />
  <meta name="description" content="templatename" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Evenementen</title>
  <link href="https://localhost/index.php/leden/evenementen" rel="canonical" />
  <link href="/templates/templatename/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jui/css/bootstrap-extended.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/system/css/frontediting.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/frontediting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
            new JCaption('img.caption');
        });
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
            jQuery('.hasPopover').popover({"html": true,"trigger": "hover focus","container": "body"});
        });
window.setInterval(function(){var r;try{r=window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new        ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(e){}if(r){r.open("GET","./",true);r.send(null)}},840000);
  </script>
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="/templates/templatename/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script src="/templates/templatename/js/global.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dollar alias is probably not being reserved for jQuery as it may be used by MooTools. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ...
```

or the shorthand:

```
jQuery(function($) { ...
```

This creates a jQuery object and passes the dollar alias as an argument so it's available inside.

Another possibility is that jQuery is already loaded (Bootstrap depends on it), and you've doubled up. This breaks things. Check your page source and make sure there's only one instance of jQuery being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not a exactly solution but works for me in some situation.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
 if(typeof $!="undefined"){   //check whether jQuery is loaded or not

  $( "#button" ).click(
    function() {
        $("#button").addClass("btn-primary");
    }
    );
  clearInterval(interval);
 }
},500)
```

Here I'm assuming jquery is not loaded yet.